# Module in angularjs similar to filter.js

Tags: angularjs

I like to create a page with dynamic filters like: 
http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/index.html
This page is based on filter.js. I'm searching for an alternative written in angularjs.
It needs to have the same functionality like the filters and pagination.

I've found ng-table (http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) which looks pretty good but maybe there are other modules to easily create e.g. range filter or checkboxes filter.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to include another package - Angular has filters built in: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

In the case of that page, you'd have something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in data.movies | rating | search | etc....">
```

Comment: Do you know how to combine this with pagination and save all the filter states in the url (hash)?

Comment: @user2874204 yes, but you should be focusing on getting the basics working first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with range/slider filter I suggest to work with the following module: 
[AngularJS RangeSlider](http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/demo/).

For interaction with ckeckboxes in Angular I recommend to use the following directive: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

But I want to note that all of them can be wrote with filters from the the Angular box.
Please, read about Angular [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).